# How do I initialize a timespan with seconds

Tags: c#

I have a variable(double) that holds a acumulation of seconds.

I would like to use timespan to format this into hours:min:seconds for display purposes, but I can't seem to find how I would assign this acumulated value to a timespace.

C#
.net 2.0

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the [TimeSpan.FromSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx) method.

Comment: What if there's more than 24 hours?

Comment: I don't see any indication that TimeSpan.FromSeconds can't handle more than 24 hours' worth of ticks.  TimeSpan can handle basically any span of time.  It can't return months or years because the number of months or years depends on the date, since not all months have the same number of days.  But it can hold months' or years' worth of days.